# Distributed environment ideas

Tags: time, process, communication, global, distributed

I need to find some real applications with below assumptions:

1. We have several processes (either on the same machine, or distributed) that can communicate with each other
2. A time unit has T seconds. We have this global time accessible in each process.
3. At each T seconds the global time increases with one unit. Only the current time unit has a global data zone where processes can read/write.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a [Real-Time Operating System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) (RTOS). You may find [RTLinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTLinux) to be a useful operating system. You may also want to check these two hyperlinks.

Comment: Yes. There might be some applications inside a RTOS. The question now is if there is any specific application that could use that global memory per time unit.